# Count number of email addresses present in a file - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Count total number of valid email addresses in a file.

sample file Input:

```
Hello from me
@gmail.com
how are you doing?
abc@gmail.com will meet xyz@yahoo.com pq@yahoo.co.in about the meeting 
sharp @2PM.okay see you  yes@yahoo.co.in there.
```

Expected output: 4

I have tried using this code. but it is returning empty list.

```
import re
with open("/Downloads/email.txt",'r') as e_add:
    for lst in e_add:
        lst = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+',lst)
        print(lst)
```

output:

```
[]
[]
[]
['abc@gmail.com', 'xyz@yahoo.com', 'pq@yahoo.co.in']
['yes@yahoo.co.in']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP's code operates line by line, so the empty lists indicate that no valid emails were found on that line. One can fix this by reading the entire file into a string variable and performing the regex on that, or counting the length of each list and updating some counter.

### Counter method

```
import re

n_email_addresses = 0
with open("/Downloads/email.txt",'r') as f
    for line in f:
        emails_found = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', line)
        n_email_addresses += len(emails_found)
print(n_email_addresses)
```

### Reading entire file method

```
from pathlib import Path
import re

text = Path("/Downloads/email.txt").read_text()
emails = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', text)
n_email_addresses = len(emails)
print(n_email_addresses)
```

Answer (score 0):

have tried put the return value like this:

```
import re
def n_valid_emails():
    nmails = []
    with open("/Downloads/email.txt",'r') as e_add:
        for lst in e_add:
            lst = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+',lst)
            nmails += lst
    return len(nmails)
```

In another line:

```
print(n_valid_emails())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
valid_email_count = 0
with open("/Downloads/email.txt",'r') as e_add:
    for lst in e_add:
        lst = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+',lst)
        valid_email_count += len(lst)

print(valid_email_count)
```

Also the code at the moment appends `.in` to two of the emails. If you know each email domain will only have a single `.` then you can change the regex expression to `[\w\.-]+@[\w-]+.[\w-]+`.